# Convert 12 hr format Date time to 24 hour in pig?

Tags: datetime, apache-pig, date-format

```
02/07/2016 12:43:23.324 PM   
mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSS AM/PM    -current format 12 hr
```

Please help to convert this to 24 hour format in pig...

File in HDFS

```
02/07/2016 12:43:23.324 PM
03/08/2016 08:12:15.123 AM
```

Commands in pig :

```
date_data = LOAD 'hdfs path' as (date: chararray);

todate_data = foreach date_data generate ToDate(date,'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS');

dump todate_data;
```

Gives the following Exception.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "02/07/2016 12:43:23.324 PM" is malformed at "16 12:43:23.324 PM"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to specify the format of the input.For example, your data is in 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSS aa' format.So use the below script.

```
date_data = LOAD 'hdfs path' as (date: chararray);
todate_data = foreach date_data generate ToDate(date,'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSS aa');
dump todate_data;
```

Below is a working example.The input 4 dates are in 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSS aa' format.

**INPUT**

```
30/06/2016 02:43:23.324 PM
01/12/2016 12:43:23.324 AM
21/08/2016 06:43:23.324 PM
13/07/2016 12:43:23.324 AM
```

**SCRIPT**

```
A = LOAD 'test4.txt' AS (create_dt:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE ToDate(create_dt,'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSS aa') AS create_dt;
DUMP B;
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: @TKHN I;ve edited the answer with an example.Seems like you have to provide the format of the input data.

Comment: One question- what is -4.00 then -5.00 after milliseconds...When I converted i got - 8.00 is it related to timezone?

Comment: @TKHN TimeOffsets from UTC.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_offsets_from_UTC